# How to call variable inside other variable?

Tags: php

example: I have

```
$varOne = $varTwo;
$varTwo = "content of variable";
echo $varOne;
```

How do I get `$varTwo`'s content through `$varOne`?

Comment: Which language you are using?

Answer (score 4):

[Assign it by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference)

```
$varOne = &$varTwo;
$varTwo = "content of variable";
echo $varOne;
```

When you assign like this

```
$varOne = $varTwo;
```

you're assigning the *value* of `$varTwo` to `$varOne`. PHP does assignment by value unless you specifically tell it to do something different. In this case, since neither of the variables exist yet, PHP will create `$varTwo` and assign it a null value, then assign that value to `$varOne`, and subsequent changes to `$varTwo` will not affect the value stored in `$varOne`.

But if you assign it by reference (with `&`), you're basically pointing `$varOne` at the location where `$varTwo` stores its value, instead of directly assigning a value to it.

[You can check the documentation for a more detailed explanation.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign varTwo before you assign varTwo to varOne

```
$varTwo = "content of variable";
$varOne = $varTwo;

echo $varOne;
```

But you should be using references here so it doesn't affect values, using &$variable instead of $varTwo = $varOne type thing, so $varTwo = &$varOne;

PHP is an order language.

```
$one = "1";
echo $two;  // will be empty and not set
$two = "2";
echo $two; // will echo 2
```